# Issue with recursive function in javascript

Tags: javascript, recursion

I am practicing using recursive functions to solve some simple javascript problems.

I am running into an issue with the following code,

```
var locate = function(arr,value){
    for (var i=0; i <arr.length; i++) {
        if(typeof arr[i]=== "string") {
            console.log("string is string");
            if(arr[i]=== value) {
                console.log("This should be true");
                return true;
            }
        }
        else {
            locate(arr[i], value);
        } 
    }
}
console.log(locate(['d', 'a',['e', 'g']], 'e'));
```

I cannot get this program to return true.  It gets to the right part of the code, as it prints the statement above it.

Any help would be appreciated.  I have been banging my head at this for a couple of hours now.

Edit-@Matt Burland pointed out the fact that you need to include a return statement when calling the recursive.

Comment: What IS it returning exactly?

Comment: @LogicArtist: `undefined`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you recurse, you need to *return* the value returned by the recursive call as you unwind.

So in your `else` clause, you need:

```
return locate(arr[i], value);
```

```js
var locate = function(arr,value){
    for (var i=0; i <arr.length; i++) {
        if(typeof arr[i]=== "string") {
            console.log("string is string");
            if(arr[i]=== value) {
                console.log("This should be true");
                return true;
            }
        }
        else {
            return locate(arr[i], value);
        } 
    }
}
alert(locate(['d', 'a',['e', 'g']], 'e'));
```